# c# How to place triangles in a row horizontally?

Tags: c#

```
 Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of triangles: ");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
                    Console.Write("+");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
```

The program outputs triangles in a row vertically. How to make the program display them horizontally in a row?

[image]

Comment: My assignment is:
It is required to output from 1 to 6 right triangles to the console, depending on what number the user enters. For example, if the number 3 is sent to the program, then it is necessary to print 3 triangles, if the user enters 6, then print 6 triangles. Triangles should be displayed not in a column, but in a row. At the same time, the size of the triangles is also formed according to the number entered by the user. If the user enters the number 3, then three right triangles should be printed, the legs of which are equal to - 3rd. You can select any symbol to print triangles.

Comment: As a result, I wrote the code that is given above, but the triangles there are displayed by the program in a row vertically. And I need it horizontally..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write it horizontally, you'll need to store the values somewhere as you populate each line up to `n`. One option is storing it in an array.

For each triangle, you need to first fill it with `+` symbols, and then fill the remaining with  .

So for input 5, you would have 5 triangles, each one going from 1 triangle on the first line, 2 triangles on the second line, all the way up to 5 triangles on the fifth line. Once you're done with looping, you should end up with something like this in your array for the first triangle.

```cs
var example = new string[] {
 "+    "
,"++   "
,"+++  "
,"++++ "
,"+++++"
};
```

For the second triangle, you would add a space and then extend the existing strings so they become longer.

```cs
var example = new string[] {
 "+     +    "
,"++    ++   "
,"+++   +++  "
,"++++  ++++ "
,"+++++ +++++"
};
```

And so on and so on up the n-th triangle.

Here's the example code.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of triangles: ");
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
var lines = new string[n + 1];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++)
    {
        // populate from 0 to j     with "+" characters
        for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
            lines[j] += "+";
        // populate from j to n + 1 with " " characters
        for (int k = j; k < n + 1; k++)
            lines[j] += " ";
    }
}

// skip the first row
for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(lines[i]);
```

Here's what the output looks like:

```
Enter the number of triangles: 
5
+     +     +     +     +     
++    ++    ++    ++    ++    
+++   +++   +++   +++   +++   
++++  ++++  ++++  ++++  ++++  
+++++ +++++ +++++ +++++ +++++
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a LINQ version:

```
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
var output =
    String.Join(
        Environment.NewLine,
        Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(w =>
            String.Concat(
                Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(x =>
                    new String('+', w + 1) + new String(' ', n - w))).Trim()));
```

With `n == 3` I get this:

```
+   +   +
++  ++  ++
+++ +++ +++
```

With `n == 7` I get this:

```
+       +       +       +       +       +       +
++      ++      ++      ++      ++      ++      ++
+++     +++     +++     +++     +++     +++     +++
++++    ++++    ++++    ++++    ++++    ++++    ++++
+++++   +++++   +++++   +++++   +++++   +++++   +++++
++++++  ++++++  ++++++  ++++++  ++++++  ++++++  ++++++
+++++++ +++++++ +++++++ +++++++ +++++++ +++++++ +++++++
```

Comment: This is a pretty neat answer. Should the values of `6` just be `n` instead? i.e. `Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select( w=>` and `new String(' ', n - w)`

Comment: @EhteshChoudhury - I don't like the magic number, but the OP has a 6 stars in the bottom row of his triangles. That `6` is for that.

Comment: @EhteshChoudhury - My mistake. The OP is using `n` in both places. I missed that. I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 1):

So here it is my answer, hopefully you find it useful.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of triangles: ");
    var n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()!);

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var line = ConstructLine(n - i, i + 1, n);

        Console.Write(line);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

private static StringBuilder ConstructLine(int numberOfSpacesInARow, int numberOfStarsInARow, int totalTrees)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (var i = 0; i < totalTrees; i++)
    {
        WriteNStars(numberOfStarsInARow, ref sb);
        WriteNSpaces(numberOfSpacesInARow, ref sb);
    }

    return sb;
}

private static void WriteNSpaces(int numberOfSpaces, ref StringBuilder sb)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfSpaces; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(' ');
    }
}

private static void WriteNStars(int numberOfStars, ref StringBuilder sb)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++)
    {
        sb.Append('*');
    }
}
```