# c# How to replace the for loop?

Tags: c#

```
var input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
for (var i = 1; i <= input; i++)
{
    for (var tr = 1; tr <= input; tr++)
    {
        for (var ch = 1; ch <= input; ch++)
        {
            if (ch <= i) Console.Write("+");
            else Console.Write(" ");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The program outputs triangles. The code uses three loops. How to make it so that there are only two loops and the program works the same as before?

[image]

Comment: Do you know what each of the `for`-loops are doing? One does number of triangles, one does height of each, and one does the width of each (not in that order). What do you think you'd be able to cut out to have the same result?

Comment: You should do your homework yourself.

Comment: Interesting, this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69548118/c-sharp-how-to-place-triangles-in-a-row-horizontally which was answered yesterday.

Comment: _"works the same as before"_ == "produces the same output", right?

Comment: replace the inner loop with Console.Write(new string('+', i).PadRight(' ', input);

Comment: @HimBromBeere you can replace one of the loops because the three variables are not independent. The number of stars in any given line is a f(number of current line).

Comment: Note that each line contains a repeated pattern (for each triangle the same amount of '+' and spaces. So it is possible to replace the second loop as well.

Comment: @zaggler It's an assignement, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

Notice in the pattern of triangles that on the first line you print 1 `+` then print n-1 blanks repeatedly. On the second line you print two `+` then print n-2 blanks repeatedly.

To decide if you need to print a plus or a blank you can use modulo arithmetics. if c % n < lineno print + else print a blank.

You print n * n characters in each line.

That's not the complete code but a good boost to implement the solution.